# How to use the Redux-toolkit thunk in the NextJS App Router server component

Tags: next.js, redux-toolkit

I want to get products from the server in the server component, to transfer the props to the client component for display there. I need to use createAsyncThunk from the redux-toolkit. But I can't call the created Thunk, because actions, selectors, dispatch, and so on cannot be used in server components. It is createAsyncThunk that needs to be used.

Thunk

```
import { createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import {
ProductsResponseDto,
DefaultRejectValue,
ExtraParamsThunkType,
} from "@/types/types";
import { api } from "@/api/api";

export const getProductsThunk = createAsyncThunk\<
ProductsResponseDto,
undefined,
ExtraParamsThunkType\<DefaultRejectValue\>

> ("products", async (\_, { rejectWithValue }) =\> {
> try {
> const { data } = await api.get("products");

    return data;

} catch (error) {
return rejectWithValue(error as DefaultRejectValue);
}
});
```

Server component

```
import Link from "next/link";
import { Products } from "@/components/products/products";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Get started with Gscore today!</h1>
      <div>
        <Products />
      </div>
      <div>Have more than 10 sites?</div>
      <Link href={"/"}>Contact us</Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Client component

```
"use client";
import { FC } from "react";
import ProductItem from "@/components/products/product/product";
import { Product } from "@/types/types";
import { useAppSelector, useAppDispatch } from "@/store/hooks";
import { selectors, actions } from "@/store";

interface ProductsProps {
  products: Product[];
}

export const Products: FC = () => {
  const products = useAppSelector(selectors.products.getProducts);

  return (
    <div style={style}>
      {" "}
      {products &&
        products.map((product) => {
          return <ProductItem key={product.id} product={product} />;
        })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

If you write it like that, then everything works. But it's Thunk that I need to use.

```
import axios from "axios";
import Link from "next/link";
import { CardsPack } from "@/components/modules/CardsPack/CardsPack";

export async function generateStaticParams() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(
      "https://somewebsite.site/api/products"
    );
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching products:", error);

    return [];
  }
}

export default async function Home() {
  const cards = await generateStaticParams();
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Get started with Gscore today!</h1>
      <div>
        <CardsPack cards={cards} />
      </div>
      <div>Have more than 10 sites?</div>
      <Link href={"/"}>
        Contact us
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```